# Plotting graphs with averages

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following data frame, and want to create a graph whose title is the date, with time on the x-axis and µmoles on the y:

```
0   2019-06-11  17:21:35    13.5
1   2019-06-11  17:22:35    13.1
2   2019-06-11  17:23:35    13.0
3   2019-06-11  17:24:35    11.8
4   2019-06-11  17:25:35    11.8
... ... ... ...
394 2019-06-11  23:55:38    0.0
395 2019-06-11  23:56:38    0.0
396 2019-06-11  23:57:38    0.0
397 2019-06-11  23:58:38    0.0
398 2019-06-11  23:59:38    0.0
```

I've written out some dataframes that separate out the timeslots, and calculates the average measurements for 5pm, 6pm, etc. For example:

```
seventeen = df.iloc[:39]  # seventeen (for 5pm)
seventeen["\u03bcmoles"].mean()

six_pm = df.iloc[39:99]   # six_pm (for 6pm)
six_pm["\u03bcmoles"].mean()
```

And so on.

I'd like to plot out a graph that uses these measurements with this sort of code:

```
df.plot(x ='Timestamp', y='\u03bcmoles', kind = 'line')
datapoints = seventeen, six_pm, seven, twenty_hundred, twenty_one, twenty_two, twenty_three (so these are all the datapoints for which I calculate the averages)
plt.show()
```

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Consider aggregating by the hour with **`pandas.Grouper`** instead of separate hourly averages.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,6))
df.plot(x ='Timestamp', y='\u03bcmoles', kind = 'line', ax=ax)

agg = (df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Timestamp', freq='h'))['\u03bcmoles'].mean()
         .reset_index()
         .set_axis(['Timestamp', 'mean_\u03bcmoles'], axis='columns', inplace=False)
      )

agg.plot(x='Timestamp', y='mean_\u03bcmoles', xticks=agg['Timestamp'].tolist(),
         kind='line', marker='o', color='green', ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

Should you need specific hours use `.loc` to filter by hour with `.isin` on the aggregated data:

```
(agg.loc[agg['Timestamp'].dt.hour.isin([17, 18, 20, 21, 22, 23])]
    .plot(x='Timestamp', y='mean_\u03bcmoles', 
          kind='line', marker='o', color='green', ax=ax)
)
```

---

To demonstrate with random data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

### DATA BUILD
np.random.seed(10262020)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp': pd.to_datetime(1603670400 + np.random.randint(1, 86400, 500), unit='s'),
                   '\u03bcmoles': np.random.uniform(50, 100, 500)
                  }).sort_values('Timestamp')

### AGGREGATION BUILD
agg = (df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Timestamp', freq='h'))['\u03bcmoles'].mean()
         .reset_index()
         .set_axis(['Timestamp', 'mean_\u03bcmoles'], axis='columns', inplace=False)
      )
      
### PLOT BUILD
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,6))
df.plot(x ='Timestamp', y='\u03bcmoles', kind = 'line', ax=ax)

agg.plot(x='Timestamp', y='mean_\u03bcmoles', 
         xticks=agg['Timestamp'].tolist() + [agg['Timestamp'].dt.ceil(freq='d').max()],
         kind='line', marker='o', color='green', ax=ax)

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

plt.show()
```

[image]